# Gtk Spinner Not Appearing

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to get a Gtk::Spinner object to display while calculations are in progress but nothing appears to be happening. The snippet of code looks like...

```
{
    Gtk::Spinner spinner;
    spinner.start (); 
    // do some work...
    spinner.stop ();
}
```

I'd have thought the spinner needed to know which dialogue it appears over but I can't see any way of feeding that into the object. Does anyone know where I could find a worked example? I can find the Gtk documentation in many places, but that isn't helping much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the mouse cursor to "busy" you can do the following:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Window> window = dialog.get_window();
if(window) {
    window->set_cursor(Gdk::Cursor(Gdk::WATCH));
    Gdk::flush();
}
```

To change it back, do

```
window->set_cursor();
```

instead.

Disclaimer: I usually work with GTK in C, and have translated this on the fly...

Comment: Thanks for the tip, ptomato. I've looked through the documentation and what you suggest appears to be what was intended. Sadly, when I do it, it makes no difference. Is there anything that needs to be done elsewhere (I tracked the execution through the if-block with a diagnostics, and tried a selection of widgets including the main dialogue for the get_window method).

Comment: Thank you, ptomato, that's done the trick. It would have been a good long while before I found that particular fact.

Answer (score 3):

In short, here is a quick checklist if **Gtk::Spinner** is not appearing on screen:

1. Make sure **librsvg** is installed.
2. Check if your currently active Gtk theme has an image file with base name "**process-working-symbolic**" (e.g. /path/to/your/theme/**icons/scalable-up-to-32/status/process-working-symbolic.svg**).
3. In your app code: Make sure you added the spinner object to some parent widget / container: `vbox.pack_start(spinner, Gtk::PACK_SHRINK);`
4. In your app code: Ensure all widgets are actually made visible: `show_all_children();`
5. In your app code: Finally you need to call `spinner.start()` for the widget to actually appear and spin on screen.

In detail:

The actual Gtk spinner widget code (see function [gtk_spinner_class_init()](https://code.woboq.org/gtk/gtk/gtk/gtkspinner.c.html#gtk_spinner_class_init) in *gtkspinner.c*) is not doing any drawing on its own. In fact its code is very little. All it does is adding CSS code to the gtk widget:

- it assigns the **CSS class** "**spinner**" to the widget
- and it automatically adds and removes the **CSS pseudo-class** "**checked**" whenever the **widget's** boolean **gtk property** "**active**" changes.

So the actual look (icon) and the animation is defined by your current theme's CSS file. E.g. in Gtk's default theme's **gtk-contained.css** file you find the following:

```
spinner {
  background: none;
  opacity: 0;
  -gtk-icon-source: -gtk-icontheme("process-working-symbolic");
};
```

Which means it will automatically search for an appropriate image file with base name "**process-working-symbolic**" in the **theme's "icons" directory tree**. And the actual spinning animation is defined in the same CSS file by this:

```
spinner:checked {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
};
```

In most other themes these CSS code portions for the spinner widget are pretty much identical.

Now here is a common problem with this: in most themes the spinner image is an SVG file (e.g. typically "**process-working-symbolic.svg**"), but the stock Gdk pixbuf loaders do not support the SVG format at all. They support a variety of other image file formats, but for actually allowing Gdk/Gtk to load .svg files you need to install a third-party pixbuf loader capable to do so like **librsvg**.

Alternative:

In case you cannot or don't want to bother to install an SVG capable Gdk pixbuf loader like **librsvg**, then you can also simply add image file(s) with the same base name, but in another file format like "**process-working-symbolic.png**" to your theme's icons directory tree. So either draw or download some spinner picture then scale it and place them several times to the resolutions listed in your theme's "icons" directory, e.g.:

```
/THEMEDIR/icons/8x8/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/16x16/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/22x22/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/24x24/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/32x32/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/64x64/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/256x256/status/process-working-symbolic.png
/THEMEDIR/icons/512x512/status/process-working-symbolic.png
```

Also you should know: Whenever you do `spinner.start()` the spinner icon immediately appears on screen, but even on a decent machine it typically takes almost a second before the spinner starts its animation.

Answer (score 2):

Did you call

```
spinner.show ();
```

and add it to some window?

Moreover, your calculations may block the UI, so it is not updated. Call

```
while (Gtk::Main::events_pending ())
    Gtk::Main::iteration ();
```

once in a while.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Now I've done spinner.show(), I realise perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree. The spinner is the thing the arrow cursor turns into while the program's doing something, no? What Motif people call a watch-cursor? If not, what is that other thing called?

Comment: Nope, the spinner is a widget like the thing that appears in the tabs of many popular browsers while the page is loading, sometimes called a "throbber". See my answer for what you want.

Comment: thank you for your help; I've no doubt your answer would have solved the question I asked, but sadly the question I asked wasn't what I needed to know. Thank you all the same.